# WPF VB.NET 4.0 DatagridComboBoxColumn binding at runtime

Tags: wpf, vb.net, .net-4.0

I had a similar question for DatagridComboboxColumn but that shown me how to use the .itemsource to bind to an array outside of the datagrid. I am having a problem trying to bind to the collection that the datagrid is bound to at runtime.

I have included a working test program for how I am approaching this.

```
Class MainWindow 

Dim ServerInfoArray As List(Of ServerInfo) = New List(Of ServerInfo)

Private Sub GetInfo(ByVal list As List(Of String))
    For Each server As String In list

        Dim tempip As ComboBoxItem = New ComboBoxItem
        Dim tempip2 As ComboBoxItem = New ComboBoxItem
        Dim sinfo As ServerInfo = New ServerInfo

        tempip.Content = "192.129.123.23"
        tempip2.Content = "23.213.223.21"

        sinfo.IPArray.Items.Add(tempip)
        sinfo.IPArray.Items.Add(tempip2)
        sinfo.ServerName = server

        ServerInfoArray.Add(sinfo)
        DataGrid1.Items.Refresh()
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim serverlist As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    serverlist.Add("Test")
    serverlist.Add("Random")
    serverlist.Add("Local")
    GetInfo(serverlist)
End Sub

Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
    Dim Col_Serial As DataGridTextColumn = New DataGridTextColumn()
    Col_Serial.Binding = New Binding("Servername")
    Col_Serial.Header = "Servername"
    Col_Serial.Width = 40

    Dim Col_IPArray = New DataGridComboBoxColumn()
    Col_IPArray.Header = "IP Addresses"
    Col_IPArray.IsReadOnly = True
    'Col_IPArray.ItemsSource = serverInfoArray ' Don't know how to do this.
    Col_IPArray.SelectedValuePath = "IPArray"
    Col_IPArray.DisplayMemberPath = "IPArray"

    DataGrid1.Columns.Add(Col_Serial)
    DataGrid1.Columns.Add(Col_IPArray)
    DataGrid1.ItemsSource = ServerInfoArray
End Sub
End Class

Class ServerInfo

Dim _Servername As String
Dim _IPArray As ComboBox
Public Property Servername() As String
    Get
        Return _Servername
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Servername = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property IPArray As ComboBox
    Get
        Return _IPArray
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ComboBox)
        _IPArray = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New()
    _Servername = Nothing
    _IPArray = New ComboBox
End Sub
End Class
```

I can get all Strings and Boolean to bind.

I do not know how I can bind this DataGridComboBoxColumn to the list of attached on the property. I cannot use XAML as I need to do this at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim Col_Serial As DataGridComboColumn = New DataGridComboColumn()
    Col_Serial.ItemSource = GetData();
    Col_Serial.SelectedValuePath = "ID_value";
    Col_Serial.DisplayMemberPath = "displya_col";
    Col_Serial.Header = "Disk4"
    Col_Serial.Width = 40
Col_Serial.IsEnabled= false;
dg.Columns.Add(Col_serial);
```

Comment: Could you give me a quick example? Also this combobox should be read only. I don't need any user input. So you mean instead of making IPArray a list(of string) it should be combobox? I thought I tried that before but I will try again.

Comment: Ok I think I am getting closer, I have to bind the itemsource externally? as the datagrid is bound to that same class array. I still cannot get any data to appear. I updated my code with what I am trying.

Comment: Yes. In windows forms, I have iterated each cell of the combobox column, and typecase explicitily as combobox and applied datasource to each.

Comment: I had created a small test program edited above - WPF .net 4.0 with a single datagrid and a button. Program works except for my combobox to show the approach I am trying to do.